# Template has_changed always true on page load with initial form value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I’m having an issue on understanding how to render a page with Django the correct way.

I would like the initial page to load with the below form only. Then after posting and getting back data, display the results.

The issue I’m having is when i add an initial end date, the page loads with anything in the if statement.

forms.py

```
class TrainingStatsForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.CharField(label='Start Date', max_length=12, widget=DateInput())
    end_date = forms.CharField(label='End Date', max_length=12, widget=DateInput(), initial=datetime.date.today)
    dog = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=k9Table.objects.all())
```

If I remove the initial=datetime.date.today. Then the page load correctly

Views.py

```
def trainingstats(request):

    if request.POST:
        date_data = TrainingStatsForm(request.POST)
        if date_data.is_valid():
            start_date = date_data.cleaned_data['start_date']
            end_date = date_data.cleaned_data['end_date']
            dog = date_data.cleaned_data['dog']

            requested_search_training = TrainingTable.objects.filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date,
                                                                         dog=dog).order_by('-date')

            requested_search_detection = DetectionTable.objects.filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date,
                                                                           dog=dog).order_by('-date')

            requested_search = sorted(
                chain(requested_search_training, requested_search_detection),
                key=lambda data: data.created, reverse=True

else:
        date_data = TrainingStatsForm()
        requested_search_training = None
        requested_search_detection = None
        requested_search = None
        total_time = 0

    content = {
        'returned_data': returned_data,
        'date_data': date_data,
        'requested_search': requested_search,
    }

    return render(request, 'trainingstats.html', content)
```

Template

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
                {{ date_data.dog|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
                {{ date_data.start_date|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
                {{ date_data.end_date|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>

</form>
{% if date_data.has_changed %} 
// show table with results of search
```

The goal is to show the form with the current date as the end date of first load. Then when the user submits the search is displays the results. Any help?

Comment: try to call your form in GET request with initial data, i.e. date_data = TrainingStatsForm({'end_date'=datetime.date.today})

Comment: doing this date_data = TrainingStatsForm({'end_date': datetime.date.today}) worked but it was the same result as adding initial to the forms.py. this also triggered the has_changed. I'm still lookinf for a way to load initial data but not trigger has_changed.